# Let Host use Guest internet connection

Tags: virtualbox

Host: Linux Mint 21. Guest: Win10
I have to use a vpn client (zywall) that is only available on Windows.
I don't even know if it's possible, but I would like to use the Guest connection (connected via zywall) by the Host machine, almost as a second network interface.

Comment: Though not perfect, you may consider a SOCKs approach like this: https://www.hostdime.com/kb/hd/security/browsing-the-internet-through-an-ssh-tunnel-on-macos